# My phone handles RAM utterly wrong

Tags: keyboard, ram, warranty

Well I don't mind if there is only very few unused RAM. That's what RAM is for. But please, my Sony Xperia SP has 1GB RAM, which is I think should absolutely be enough for the tasks that my phone needs to handle, but it's intensely abused by factory Android and factory applications.

I only use a few apps on my phone: Gmail, Hangouts, Chrome, Spotify, Calendar and NewsBlur.

Some really annoying things that occur on regular daily usage, and can easily be reproduced:

- I open a news page in Chrome, which has a couple high resolution photos - but nothing extremely much, maybe a few tens of megabytes uncompressed image data. (Or a few megabytes compressed). And boom! Chrome disappears instantly!
- I'm typing a message on a web service, or fill basically any form on any website, that consist more that a few paragpraphs without images - either the browser or the keyboard application disappears randomly. On some websites, it impossible to type a full sentence. Does not matter if I use the factory keyboard, or SwiftKey.
- It's essentially impossible to listen to music and browse the web at the same time. One of the applications gets killed after a short while.
- Sometimes can't even text and listen to music at the same time.

Since my old Sony Ericsson cellphone could handle all of these without any problem ever, with one quarter of this memory, or so, I think either something is wrong with my phone, or it's firmware is totally unusable. I lean towards the second one, since my girlfriend's Sony phone has the same issues. And also, I don't think it's a hardware problem, since other applications run totally smoothly and with zero problem. NewsBlur and Calendar works perfectly, and I've tried installing some performance-hungry games, all of them run perfectly fine and smoothly.

I tried many things. Factory reset did not help, disabling 90% of all applications did not help, trying different keyboard software, music player, browser did not help much. I removed all the applications that I don't use on a daily basis, etc.

If I use a lightweight homescreen instead of the factory one, and switch to Dolphin browser or Opera Mini, things get a *little* better, but each problem happens on a daily basis anyway.

I have up-to-date firmware and applications.

What annoying is that Android seems to keep applications cached like homescreen, Play Store, etc. It's great that homescreen loads instantly, but I don't mind it killed, if that's required to keep keyboard in memory (while I'm typing, at least!)

What am I doing wrong? Is this normal? (It should not be...) Should I send a warranty claim?

I think it should work for so simple tasks out of the box, but I'm open to anything that helps. Unfortunately, on Google and Sony support forums I could not find anything aside clearing application data and using less applications. I already use less applications that I've used on my non-smartphone, and clearing application data did only rarefied the issues very little, and then everything went back to "normal", after a day or so.

So clearing application data does not really solve the problem. Also, I don't want useful information to be lost, so I think clearing application data regularly is not an option. For me, it seems that factory applications are so poorly designed, that they prefer loading huge amount of unimportant information to RAM, and killing really important applications to make space for it. And there is always still at least 150-200 megabytes of RAM left, when applications start to get killed...

Comment: Chrome is usually power hungry try  other browsers like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mkrtchyan.aospinstaller&hl=en

Comment: If you are rooted try removing this bloatwares and use greenify for better ram management

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, I use factory firmware. My device is not rooted. But I don't think this should be necessary. I tried many other lightweight options, that use just a small fraction of memory that Chrome uses. This did not solve the problem completely. I'm going to try Greenify, since it says to work on factory ROM. Thanks!